# Find contradiction in list

Tags: python, list, logic

I have many lists and I want to find if any is contradict to others.
a list would not conflict by them self and all relation are only `'>'` and `'<'`:

```
list1 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<3", "d<6"]
list2 = ["b<6", "a<1", "c<5", "d<2"]
list3 = ["a>7", "c<2", "b>1", "d<8"]
```

In above case, `list3` is contradict to `list1` since `"a"` can't greater than 7 and smaller than 4 at the same time.

Another example

```
list4 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c>2", "d<8"]
list5 = ["b<6", "a<6", "c<5", "d>9"]
list6 = ["a>2", "b>1", "d<8", "c<9"]
```

In this case, `list5` is contradict to `list4` since `"d"` can't greater than 9 and smaller than 8 at the same time.

Comment: Are variables always positioned on the same indices?

Comment: where is the code, you tried?

Comment: sorry for unclear, actually, the variable will change their position in different list

Comment: @jimmy15923: will a list sometimes be in conflict with itself, like `list1=["a<1","a>2"]`? Furthermore are all the relations `<` and `>`? Please consider rewriting your question specifying the problem better. Right now it has a lot of open ends.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, a list would not conflict by them self.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR I have only come out to catch a variable which contains both ">" and"<" in whole list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply maintain a **list per variable containing the upper and lower bound**. In case the variable has no upper or lower bound, `None` can be used.

Each time you evaluate a constraint, you update the list accordingly, and when the lower bound becomes larger than the upper bound, we know that there is a conflict.

Now we only need a few parts:

- a *parsing* step that derives the constraints;
- a *variable manager* that maintains and checks the bounds.

The variable manager can work as follows:

```
def update_variables(var_dict,variable,constraint,value):
    la = var_dict.get(variable)
    if la is None:
        la = [None,None]
        var_dict[variable] = la
    if constraint == '>' and (la[0] is None or value > la[0]):
        la[0] = value
    elif constraint == '<' and (la[1] is None or value < la[1]):
        la[1] = value
    return la[0] is None or la[1] is None or la[0] < la[1]
```

First we check if the variable is already part of the dictionary. If not we add `[None,None]`. Next we update the bound by updating the index that correspond to the constraint (0 for `'>'` and 1 for `'<'`). We finally check if the bound is still possible. That is the case, we return `True`. Otherwise we return `False`. From the moment such bound errors, we know that the two lists are conflicting.

Now we still need to process the lists and update the manager accordingly. Therefore we developed a regex:

```
(\w+)\s*(<|>)\s*(-?\d+)
```

So here we assume that every string has the format `\w+` (the name of the variable), followed by a `'<'` or `'>'` and finally a value `-?\d+`. Each time we fetch such string from the list, parse it, update the manager and check if the configuration is still valid. So this looks like:

```
import re

def conflict(lista,listb):
    manager = {}
    rgx = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*(<|>)\s*(-?\d+)')
    for listi in (lista,listb):
        for constraint in listi:
            mat = rgx.match(constraint)
            if mat:
                var,con,val = mat.groups()
                val = int(val)
                if not update_variables(manager,var,con,val):
                    return True # the lists are conflicting
            else:
                raise Exception('Could not parse constraint "%s"'%constraint)
    return False # the lists do not conflict
```

This generates:

```
>>> conflict(list3,list1)
True
>>> conflict(list1,list1)
False
>>> conflict(list1,list2)
False
>>> conflict(list1,list3)
True
>>> conflict(list2,list3)
True
```

Comment: I am wondering if I want to know which variable is conflicted, how should I do? I have tried 
    if la[1] < la[0]:
        return variable

Comment: @jimmy15923: all variables? or the first that fails?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have already come out the answer.
if la[1] != None and la[0]!= None and la[1] < la[0]:
    return var
Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

You could try SymPy.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')
list1 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<3", "d<6"]
list2 = ["b<6", "a<1", "c<5", "d<2"]
list3 = ["a>7", "c<2", "b>1", "d<8"]

l1 = [parse_expr(eq) for eq in list1]
l2 = [parse_expr(eq) for eq in list2]
l3 = [parse_expr(eq) for eq in list3]

print(solve(l1 + l2))
print(solve(l1 + l3))
print(solve(l2 + l3))
```

The strings in your lists will be parsed to inequalities with `parse_expr`. Then you have to concatenate the lists with `+` and try to solve 8 inequalities at once. If you get `False`, then it is not possible and you therefore have a contradiction. Else you get some expression for the correct values of `a, b, c, d` to fulfill the inequalities. So you could write something like this:

```
def contradiction(l_i, l_j):
    s = solve(l_i + l_j)
    if s==False: return True
    else: return False
```

Of course if you have many lists of strings, then you have to find a way to combine all lists as I did here manually as there are only the three combinations `l1 + l2`, `l1 + l3` and `l2 + l3`. Also you should note that for large lists the performance could get bad.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, to no avail. Do you happen to know why `simplify(And(Rel(a, 4, '<'),Rel(a, 5, '>')))` isn't `False` for sympy?

Comment: I'm **guessing** that `simplify` doesn't try to _solve_ this relation that has obviously no solution but instead only tries to simplify it.